# Issues with Asynchronous Reads in .NET - it seems that my callback is being called multiple times when it should not be

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Basically I'm writing some code for a system that is designed to be very fast, small, and robust. I started off with some asynchronous examples for `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` and wrote a Server and Client class that is basically used in multiple places in my project.

Basically my server class (code will be below later) is all event based, and so is the client code. When I get packets - one by one - coming in through either a server or client socket - everything works fine.

However, if the sender - for example class A uses Client Class - sends a bunch of packets through a TCP Stream to the Server class in Class B.. Naturally the server class may get all the packets as one big lump sump. So when the callback for data recieved event occurs, I grab the buffer and then process it.

And here's where something funny happens. My issue isn't splitting all the packets out from a big buffer. My problem is that for some reason that I cannot understand.. Lets say I send 5 packets from Client to Server (or vice versa) and the other side gets all 5. The datarecieve event triggers, and then the bugger is grabbed and all 5 packets are in there. They are processed. But then the event triggers again..

In other words, instead of the event triggering one time, it triggers 5 times for 5 individual packets, and I end up processing a buffer containing those 5 packets 5 times.

And since I'm designing a distributed network, that means the node that the module talks to (module (Client Class) <--> node (Server Class) <--> client (Client Class)) gets 25 packets instead of 5. And then it forwards those on to the destination, which gets 25*5 or 125 packets.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here. I've tried thinking of ways to make the event fire just once.. And I might end up tossing in my towel and rewrite the Server and Client classes so that they will be synchronous and have a thread per client instance (or on server side, a thread that does accepts, and a thread per client connection) - so that way I can handle the data flow better. I.e. packet comes in, if its whole, process. If its not, wait for it to be whole, etc.. using the typical start/end special bytes and so forth.

Server Class - most of it is there. Took out some of the irrevelant ones like KillClient, etc.

```
   public class Server
{
    private TcpListener serverListener;
    private List<ServerClient> clients;

    #region Callbacks


    public delegate void incomingDataCallback(byte[] buffer, string clientID, TcpClient tcpClient);
    public incomingDataCallback incomingData = null;

    public delegate void incomingConnectionCallback(string clientID, TcpClient tcpClient);
    public incomingConnectionCallback incomingConnection = null;

    public delegate void connectionClosedCallback(string clientID, TcpClient tcpClient);
    public connectionClosedCallback connectionClosed = null;

    public delegate void dataWrittenCallback(string clientID, TcpClient tcpClient);
    public dataWrittenCallback dataWritten = null;


    #endregion

    // Constructor
    public Server(string listenIP, int listenPort)
    {
        // Create a new instance of serverlistener.
        serverListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(listenIP), listenPort);
        this.clients = new List<ServerClient>();
        this.Encoding = Encoding.Default;
    }

    ~Server()
    {
        // Shut down the server.
        this.Stop();
    }

    public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TcpClient> TcpClients
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (ServerClient client in this.clients)
            {
                yield return client.TcpClient;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TcpClient> TcpClients
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (ServerClient client in this.clients)
            {
                yield return client.TcpClient;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.serverListener.Stop();
        lock (this.clients)
        {
            foreach (ServerClient client in this.clients)
            {
                client.TcpClient.Client.Disconnect(false);
                if (connectionClosed != null)
                    connectionClosed(client.ID, client.TcpClient);
            }
            this.clients.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void WriteToClient(TcpClient tcpClient, byte[] bytes)
    {
        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        try
        {
            networkStream.BeginWrite(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, WriteCallback, tcpClient);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            // Port was closed before data could be written. 
            // So remove this guy from clients.
            lock (this.clients)
            {
                foreach (ServerClient cl in clients)
                {
                    if (cl.TcpClient.Equals(tcpClient))
                    {
                        this.clients.Remove(cl);
                        if (connectionClosed != null)
                            connectionClosed(cl.ID, cl.TcpClient);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = result.AsyncState as TcpClient;
        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        networkStream.EndWrite(result);

        // Get the ID and return it
        //ServerClient client = result.AsyncState as ServerClient;

        //string ipaddr = ((IPEndPoint)(tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Address.ToString();
        string port = ((IPEndPoint)(tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Port.ToString();


        Console.WriteLine("Write callback called for: " + port);

        //                if (dataWritten != null)
        //                  dataWritten(client.ID, tcpClient);
    }

    private void AcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient;

        try
        {
            tcpClient = serverListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Often get this error when shutting down the server
            return;
        }

        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];

        // Get the IP Address.. this will be used for id purposes. 
        string ipaddr = ((IPEndPoint)(tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Address.ToString();
        string port = ((IPEndPoint)(tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Port.ToString();

        // Create a client object for this client.
        ServerClient client = new ServerClient(tcpClient, buffer, ipaddr + ":" + port);

        Console.WriteLine("Data availiable: " + networkStream.DataAvailable.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Amount of data: " + tcpClient.Available.ToString());

        // Lock the list and add it in.
        lock (this.clients)
        {
            this.clients.Add(client);
        }

        if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
        {

            int read = networkStream.Read(client.Buffer, 0, client.Buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Calling ReadHandle directly with " + read.ToString() + " number of bytes. for clientid: " + client.ID);
            ReadHandle(client, read, networkStream);

        }
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Started beginRead for client in accept connection: " + client.ID);
            networkStream.BeginRead(client.Buffer, 0, client.Buffer.Length, ReadCallback, client);
            //networkStream.

            Console.WriteLine("Data availiable: " + networkStream.DataAvailable.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of data: " + tcpClient.Available.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Starting BeginAcceptTcpClient again - client: " + client.ID);
        serverListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTcpClientCallback, null);

        // Notify owner that new connection came in
        if (incomingConnection != null)
            incomingConnection(client.ID, tcpClient);
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ServerClient client = result.AsyncState as ServerClient;


        if (client == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReadCallback: Null client");
            return;
        }

        int read = 0;

        NetworkStream networkStream = client.NetworkStream;
        try
        {
            read = networkStream.EndRead(result);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReadCallback: Exception occured during reading.. Message: " + ex.Message + " client " + client.ID);
            lock (this.clients)
            {
                this.clients.Remove(client);
                if (connectionClosed != null)
                    connectionClosed(client.ID, client.TcpClient);
                return;
            }

        }

        ReadHandle(client, read, networkStream);
    }

    private void ReadHandle(ServerClient client, int read, NetworkStream networkStream)
    {



        // If zero bytes read, then client disconnected.
        if (read == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReadHandle: Read == 0, closing connection for Client: " + client.ID);
            lock (this.clients)
            {
                this.clients.Remove(client);
                if (connectionClosed != null)
                    connectionClosed(client.ID, client.TcpClient);
                return;
            }
        }

        //string data = this.Encoding.GetString(client.Buffer, 0, read);

        // Do something with the data object here.
        if (incomingData != null)
            incomingData(client.Buffer, client.ID, client.TcpClient);

        // Go back to accepting data from client.
        try
        {
          networkStream.BeginRead(client.Buffer, 0, client.Buffer.Length, ReadCallback, client);
            Console.WriteLine("ReadHandle: BeginRead called for client " + client.ID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Damn, we just lost the client.
            Console.WriteLine("ReadHandle: Exception occured during trying to BeginRead.. Message: " + ex.Message + " client " + client.ID);
            lock (this.clients)
            {
                this.clients.Remove(client);
                if (connectionClosed != null)
                    connectionClosed(client.ID, client.TcpClient);
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}

internal class ServerClient
{
    public ServerClient(TcpClient tcpClient, byte[] buffer, string ipaddr)
    {
        if (tcpClient == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("tcpClient");
        if (buffer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("tcpClient");
        if (ipaddr == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("tcpClient");

        this.TcpClient = tcpClient;
        this.Buffer = buffer;
        this.ID = ipaddr;
    }

    public TcpClient TcpClient { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }
    public string ID { get; private set; }
    public NetworkStream NetworkStream
    {
        get
        {
            return TcpClient.GetStream();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here's the client class - it's smaller and simple compared to the server.

```
public class Client
{
    private IPAddress address;
    private int port;
    private string ID;

    //private WaitHandle addressSet;
    private TcpClient tcpClient;
    private int failedConnectionCount;

    public bool keepOnTrying = false;

    #region Callbacks

    public delegate void incomingDataCallback(byte[] buffer, string serverID);
    public incomingDataCallback incomingData = null;


    public delegate void connectedCallback(string serverID);
    public connectedCallback clientConnected = null;

    public delegate void connectionFailedCallback(string serverID);
    public connectionFailedCallback clientConnectionFailed = null;

    public delegate void connectionClosedCallback(string serverID);
    public connectionClosedCallback connectionClosed = null;

    public delegate void dataWrittenCallback(string serverID);
    public dataWrittenCallback dataWritten = null;

    #endregion

    public Client(IPAddress address, int port)
    {
        this.address = address;

        if (port < 0) throw new ArgumentException();

        this.port = port;
        this.tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        this.Encoding = Encoding.Default;
        this.ID = address.ToString() + ":" + port.ToString();

        tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize = 16384;
        tcpClient.SendBufferSize = 16384;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Client()
    {
        this.Disconnect();
    }

    public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }


    public void Connect()
    {
        tcpClient.BeginConnect(address, port, ConnectCallback, null);
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        tcpClient.Close();
        if (connectionClosed != null)
            connectionClosed(ID);
    }

    public void Write(byte[] bytes)
    {
        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        networkStream.BeginWrite(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, WriteCallback, null);
    }

    private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        if (tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            networkStream.EndWrite(result);
        }

        if (dataWritten != null)
            dataWritten(ID);
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // Check to see if connected successfully or not. If we didnt, then the try/catch block will increment
        // the failed connection count.
        try
        {
            tcpClient.EndConnect(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref failedConnectionCount);
            if (keepOnTrying)
                tcpClient.BeginConnect(address, port, ConnectCallback, null);

            if (clientConnectionFailed != null)
                clientConnectionFailed(ID);

            return;
        }

        // Connected successfully.
        // Now begin async read operation.

        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
        networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReadCallback, buffer);

        if (clientConnected != null)
            clientConnected(ID);
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        int read;
        NetworkStream networkStream;

        try
        {
            networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            read = networkStream.EndRead(result);

        }
        catch
        {
            // An error has occured when reading.. -.-
            Console.WriteLine("Error occured while reading for ID: " + ID);
            return;
        }



        // If read is 0, then connection was closed

        if (read == 0)
        {
            if (connectionClosed != null)
                connectionClosed(ID);
            return;
        }

        if (result.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uh oh ");
        }

        byte[] buffer = result.AsyncState as byte[];

        if (incomingData != null)
            incomingData(buffer, ID);

        // Then begin reading again.
        networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReadCallback, buffer);
    }

}
```

And the way I use those classes is this:

1. Create a Class and then make an object of either server or client.
2. Tie in all the callbacks. I.e. create functions in your class for each of the callbacks.
3. Call server start, or client connect. Depending on which you are using.

So to replicate my problem, do this:

1. Make a server class in one program, and client in another. Have the client connect to the server.
2. Do a callback for the data coming in. I use serialization, so you could do something similiar.
3. Have the client send a bunch of data to the server all at once. For me, I'm converting JSON data into my own format in my Module, and then I send it to the server. So the server gets a bunch of packets at once.
4. Should be seeing - if its fast enough - that the server will get all of the packets into the receiving buffer AND every time it calls the incomingDataCallback - you will have a buffer with all the packets in it. And it will call that for every packet received. Not byte, whole packets.

So before I go and rewrite the code to be synchronous and run in a thread(s):

1. Is there anything I could do different / better to make it so that way when the data comes in - either it calls the event once and I can process all the packets in the buffer - or -
2. Is there a way to make sure that any other events that get called will not share the same buffer as the initial one? I know its a waste of processor time - but I can have an "if first 10 bytes are 00, return" line in my incomingDataCallback handler. That's why I was thinking of making buffer all nulled out in the first event and detect those on the subsequent events.

Update: Due to Servy's comment - here's how I use these classes. Not c/p'ing everything, just the relevant parts.

Node - uses Server class.

```
class ModuleClient
{
    private List<ModuleClientInfo> clients = new List<ModuleClientInfo>();
    private Server myServer = null;

    public ModuleClient()
    {
        // create a server object
        myServer = new Server("127.0.0.1", 9000);

        // Attach callbacks
        myServer.connectionClosed = connClosed;
        myServer.dataWritten = dataWritten;
        myServer.incomingConnection = incomingConn;
        myServer.incomingData = incomingData;
    }

    public void startListeningForModules()
    {
        if (!listeningForModules)
            myServer.Start();
        else
            return;

        listeningForModules = true;
    }

    private void incomingData(byte[] buffer, string clientID, TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data from " + clientID);

        incomingPacketStruct newPacket = new incomingPacketStruct();
        newPacket.clientID = clientID;
        newPacket.buffer = buffer;
        newPacket.tcpClient = tcpClient;
    }
```

Its in incomingData that I notice I'm having 5 packets in the buffer, and then incomingData is called 5 times.

Now as for the client's incomingData (keep in mind I have not noticed this behavior in outgoing data, nor is it relevant. Lets say I get 10 json packets all at once, I will send them on to the node - so thats 10 writes. The node will get them all in the same buffer, which then will call the server's incoming data 10 times and each time, it will see 10 packets.

Client's incoming data:

```
public partial class Program : ServiceBase
{
   // Globals
    private static SocketObject.Client myHermesClient = null;
    private static JSONInterface myJsonInterface = null;

    private static void mainThread(object data)
    {

        // Take care of client and callbacks..
        myHermesClient = new SocketObject.Client(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9000);
        myHermesClient.connectionClosed = hermesConnectionClosed;
        myHermesClient.clientConnected = hermesConnected;
        myHermesClient.dataWritten = hermesDataWritten;
        myHermesClient.incomingData = hermesIncomingData;
        myHermesClient.clientConnectionFailed = hermesConnectionFailed;

        myHermesClient.keepOnTrying = true;

        // Begin async connect
        myHermesClient.Connect();


        // Main loop for service.
        while (serviceRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

    }

    #region Hermes Client Code
    private static void hermesIncomingData(byte[] buffer, string serverID)
    {

    }
```

And again, same thing. When the server sends a lot of data back to the client.. If you break and look at the buffer, you will see what I'm talking about.

Now, want to make this clear.. My issue is NOT breaking up the packets. I have code (not included because proprietary, and not relevant to this - it does not modify buffer, only creates a list of objects from it) - but the issue is the callback being called multiple times as stated above.

Comment: FWIW, this is one of the best thought out and explained questions I've seen around here. Upvote for that alone!

Comment: Thanks. :) Was hoping I didn't over do it. I think more is less (as long its relevant) so people can help instead of second-guessing.

Comment: So you've included a lot of code that doesn't seem necessary, and excluded code that *is* necessary.  First off, when you use events, you should actually use events (i.e. use the `event` keyword for your events) and not just a plain delegate.  You never actually show the code where the your "events" are initialized, or how this server class is used (i.e. the entry point).  That's likely where the problem is.

Comment: Servy - updated my question to show you how I used the classes. To be blunt, I did give an example of how to use the classes before your comment. In addition to that, I've tracked the issue down to BeginRead and EndRead, which are in the server and client classes. I did not want to include too much code - and instead include the code that is pertinent to my question. As for events, all the examples I've seen use callbacks, but I can look into using events. I originally got this code from: http://robjdavey.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/asynchronous-tcp-server-example/ - and modified it.

Comment: I updated the code a few days ago to show where I initialize the callbacks. I also looked at the differences between events and callbacks. You can use callbacks instead of events. Even Microsoft's documentation for EndRead (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.endread%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) uses callbacks not event handlers. The whole point of my question is that the callback I pass to BeginRead gets called for every packet - i.e. if 5 packets come in, gets called 5 times, even if all 5 are in buffer on the first call).. Am I doing something wrong, or?

Comment: Or how do I fix it? The reason why I posted the past two comments is because I didn't get any response from Servy and saw an upvote on Servy's comment. I'm very confident the issue is in the Server and/or Client class and has nothing to do with event keyword because I'm using callbacks - unless I should be using events instead? Yet I see examples for callbacks in microsoft's example and other examples that use BeginRead and EndRead.. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: First of all, I would try to isolate the misbehaving component. Use a packet sniffing tool like WireShark to determine if the server is emitting 25 packets, or if the client is receiving 5 and firing unnecessary Receive events.

Comment: Just a quick thought - but is this a standard asynch type issue where the thread does a test and then before it closes the gate (presumably removes its data from the buffer, the next thread does its test and they all find data there before any of the data has been removed from the buffer - and so they all process (I apologise if it isn't this as I haven't closely analysed the source)

Comment: Stared at this code for a long time.  You wrote **(Client Class) <--> node (Server Class) <--> client (Client Class)** which implies that the client sends something, the server receives it, and then the server "echoes" it back out to all the other clients?  If that is the case, I don't see any code that does this part.  If you are doing this, is it possible that you incorrectly echoing the data back to the source of the data in the first place?  You'd have to exclude the source in your for loop.  This doesn't explain all your symptoms...just a thought.

Comment: Oh!...in Server.WriteToClient() you have a bug in the Catch() block.  You are incorrectly modifying the "clients" List by removing one of the items while inside a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)`

```
ReadHandle(client, read, networkStream);
```

Then inside `ReadHandle()` you setup the call back again.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous networking code is tricky enough, not having all your code probably makes this impossible to solve. I'll answer with some thoughts:

1. The library you're using is solid; I doubt that TcpClient, TcpListener, or NetworkStream are the problem.
2. You're re-using the same buffer over and over. Your `incomingData()` method doesn't appear to mirror the data but rather re-use the same underlying buffer; but then again, it does nothing, so you've obviously clipped out functions there that might change this behavior.
3. You cannot be guaranteed that a packet will contain the exact same chunk of data that you called with Write; you'll need to do the "if a packet is whole, process it; otherwise, wait for more data to come in" thing. This usually means pulling data out of the buffer that you give to BeginRead and copying it to a different buffer.
4. You'll want a lot more debugging info. One commenter suggested WireShark and I repeat that recommendation; that will help you disambiguate client problems from server-side problems. Likewise, you should log the number of bytes pulled off the wire with each call to ReadHandle.

Really, you just need more debugging info. That should make it clear why you're appearing to get five packets each with five blocks of data.